# Change in display and input date format in Idempiere 7.1 does not occur when format is updated in language

Tags: idempiere

FreeBSD-12.1p10 (jail) PostgreSQL-11.8 Idempiere 7.1

This question was also asked on the Idempiere mailing list and has received no answer.

A new test client/tenant was created.  Its language was set to `en_CA`.  Following the breadcrumb path to ***menu==>sysadmin==>gen-rules==>sys-rules-==>language*** the language record for en_CA has the date format set to `yyyy-MM-dd` and has the System Language option checked.  The cache has been reset.  There are no open windows for the test client.

When a custom window containing a date field is opened and a date is chosen from the date picker then it displays the date as MM/dd/yyyy.

That window was closed. The underlying table column for that field was updated on the data dictionary to have the format 'yyyy-MM-dd', the cache was reset, and the window was reopened.  Again the date selected from the date picker was displayed as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

How does one get date fields to accept input and display values in a particular format?

I have a similar problem with time input and display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the date format is affected by the language you select on login time, not by the language defined on the tenant.